# Best Practice: Sending Objects over TCP/IP between Platforms

Tags: c#, java, .net, winforms, tcp

I want to make an application which can send an object to an other application.

One will be developed in .NET (C# Winforms) and the other in Java. The .NET Part will be running on a Windows client, while the Java client is running on a Unix OS with low ressources (Like a Smartphone).

I'm looking for the best practice in order to send this Object (lets say Car) from my .NET Application to the Java application.

I guess I have to serialize my Object first, then send it and then I will have to deserialize it again on the Java side.

My main criteria:

- Easy, but most **important**: nice/smart
- **Generic**, if possible.

I was thinking of serializing my class `Car` and having the same class-structure on the other platform just deserializing it, automatically loading the attributes.

The application should just do that. There is a database connected to one of the plattforms, but that's not part of my problem.

I was thinking of JSON or XML Serializing, but I do not know if this is the best/smartest appproach.

I am happy for any suggestions.

Comment: **Close-Voting:** *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: I want to add that I'm not looking for a tool, a library or an off-site resource. I'm looking for a programmatical approach for my question.

Comment: On the .Net side, use WCF. On the java side, I don't know, there probably must exist a horrible java hack for this.

Comment: Are those two compatible? I was looking if there is something like a markup language common to both Java and .NET, hence generic.

Comment: xml, json, bson, protobuf... the options are plentiful...

Comment: Both have decent json support, i would look into that if i had to perform a similar task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did implement a cross-platform SSO framework that used JSON as lingua franca between platform-specific marshalling parsers.

Exchangeable namespaces and class names followed [Java common practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for the sake of both readability and name resolution.

Carrier of choice for this specific implementation was a direct TCP/IP persistent connection, but the serialization/deserialization layer should be completely agnostic about it.

Some specifics needed special care - DateTime values, for example. To avoid assumptions from both sides I adopted GMT 0-based, [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) as the reference format. Collections (arrays, lists) were worthy of attention as well.

Answer (score -1):

Could go with SOAP both sides - Various Java tools can generate/parse SOAP services and same with .NET.

If you wanted just TCP/IP communication with no overhead - use Sockets API on both sides - serialise and deserialise objects at either end.

Comment: If I serialize an object in .NET and deserialize it on Java do I have to reformat the deserialized object or are they just compatible? I could do this with a special wrapper class, but is this the best practice? Sorry I'm just trying to learn to do it right.

Comment: Probably not straight to objects (although you could always try it). I was thinking serialise to xml or json